# How to distribute a Go module with C dependencies

Tags: go, cgo, go-modules

I have a Go package—call it `foo`—I've built around some existing C code, and I'm trying to determine how best to distribute it.

A bit of background... Here's a simplified version of my directory structure:

```
foo/
  |_ include/
      |_ <several other header files>
  |_ libs/
      |_ <several .so files>
  |_ foo.c
  |_ foo.h
  |_ foo.go
```

A stripped down head of `foo.go`

```golang
package foo

// #cgo CFLAGS: -I${SRCDIR}/include
// #cgo LDFLAGS: ${SRCDIR}/_foo.so -L${SRCDIR}/libs
// #include <stdlib.h>
// #include "foo.h"
import "C"

...
```

Where `_foo.so` is a dynamic lib generated as part of the build process. I am able to run and test my code fine, but I want to be able to distribute it and use it in a separate project, one that uses `go mod`. This is where things get a bit tricky, and my understanding of Go gets flimsy. Conceptually, I simply want to be able to distribute the `foo/` directory (`.so` files and all) in a place where another application can find and import it, however there are a couple stumbling blocks I've run into:

- I can't make this a binary package, as we're on Go 1.13 and as far as I understand that capability was dropped after 1.12.
- The build process for the `.so` file is quite substantial, and I don't want other developers to have to spend 30 mins+ just building that object.

I have found a lot of CGO demos and blogs, but not a lot of explanations around how to distribute CGO packages. Any ideas?

It's worth noting that this is for my company, where the environment is standard, so I do not have to control for different OS's, etc.

### Edit

Something I forgot to mention that I've tried is baking the library into the `GOPATH` of a Docker image, and just building from that base for the microservice that depends on it. However, when building the service with `-mod=vendor`, it's unable to find the library in the `GOPATH`:

```
RUN GOOS=linux \
    GOARCH=amd64 \
    CGO_ENABLED=1 \
    GOFLAGS=-mod=vendor \
    GO111MODULE=on \
    go build \
    -o service ./cmd/serve/main.go
```

```
./service
# build foo: cannot load foo: open /.../svc/vendor/foo: no such file or directory
```

Comment: Not ideal, but maybe just commit the compiled .so file to version control. The file will be then downloaded with the module.

Comment: I'd toyed with that idea, but it's really the other `.so` files it depends on in `foo/libs` that make it too large to commit.

Comment: C dependencies should be controlled however you would control C dependencies without Go in the system. That said, I think your problem with the docker image is that you're trying to `go build` a file -- the go commands should operate on packages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For anyone who might run into a similar question in the future, here are the steps I took to make this work.

1. I baked the generated artifacts into a base docker image, a la:

```
FROM golang:1.13.4

COPY ./foo /go/src/foo/foo
COPY ./foo.mod /go/src/foo
```

This gets around having to commit the `.so` files to source control, instead simply pushing the docker image to a registry.

2. Any service that requires this library is built from that base image:

```
FROM my-foo-base:latest

COPY ./vendor ./vendor
COPY ./go.mod ./
COPY ./go.sum ./

# Put foo in /vendor so it's discoverable, and put its libs where they
# can be discovered
RUN mv /go/src/foo ./vendor && \
    mv ./vendor/foo/foo/libs/*.so /usr/lib/ && \
    mv ./vendor/foo/foo/include/* /usr/include/

# Copy in app code
COPY ./my-app ./my-app

# Required so the app can find the _foo.so shared object
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/vendor/foo/foo:/usr/lib:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}"

# Build into a single binary
RUN GOOS=linux \
    GOARCH=amd64 \
    CGO_ENABLED=1 \
    GOFLAGS=-mod=vendor \
    GO111MODULE=on \
    go build \
    -o service ./cmd/serve/main.go
```

This works, and the service is able to discover the CGO package.